# Android Studio freezes with a toolbar detached

Tags: android, android-studio

I know this question is asked a lot. But I could not find any good solution other than increasing memory.

But I don't think that this is my case - My studio just freezes and never responds.
Moreover, design editor toolbar keeps showing in all other Windows apps. I attached a screenshot for you to see how it hangs over a browser window.
[image]

Do you even know what this could be? Nothing helps other than restarting Studio.

Thanks,